# Mix HTML and {this.props.foo}

Tags: reactjs

```
        var User = React.createClass({
            render: function() {
                console.log("User");
                console.log(this.props);

                return (
                    <div className="user">
                        <h2 className="userName">
                            {this.props.name}
                        </h2>
                        <img src={this.props.avatarHash}  alt="" width="100" height="100" />
                    </div>
                );
            }
        });
```

How can I append/mix HTML with properties?
What I've tried and failed:

```
<img src="http://foo.bar/{this.props.avatarHash}" alt="" width="100" height="100" />
<img src="http://foo.bar/"{this.props.avatarHash} alt="" width="100" height="100" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
<img 
  src={ `http://foo.bar/${ this.props.avatarHash }` } 
  alt="" 
  width="100" 
  height="100" 
/>
```

or *String concatenation*

```
<img 
  src={ 'http://foo.bar/' + this.props.avatarHash } 
  alt="" 
  width="100" 
  height="100" 
/>
```